# using $.get() to reference an RSS Feed

Tags: javascript, xml, rss, jquery-isotope

in this code; *$.get('sites.xml', function (d) {* and below it,  *$(d).find('site').each(function () {* refer to an xml file. How would i reference an RSS Feed?

```
var $container = $('#container');
var $checkboxes = $('#filters a');

init();

function init(){
    $.get('sites.xml', function (d) {

        $(d).find('site').each(function () {
            var imageUrl = $(this).find('imgurl').text();
            var title = $(this).find('title').text();
            var url = $(this).find('url').text();
            var brief = $(this).find('brief').text();
            var long = $(this).find('long').text();
            var classa = $(this).find('_class').text();

            $('<div class="' + classa + '"></div>').html('<a href="' + url + '"> 
            <img  src="' + imageUrl + '" class="thumbnail" />' + '<h1>' + title + '</h1> 
            </a>').appendTo('#container');

            }); // end each

        initIsotop(); // after adding all elements - init isotop
    }); // end $.get
}

function initIsotop() {
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        transformsEnabled: false,    
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 4000,
            easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
            queue: false
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: the question is how to input the feed into the code. Sorry. The feed i'm trying to use is an XML file. But i'm not sure how to include that URL into this code.

Answer (score 0):

> the question is how to input the feed into the code. Sorry. The feed i'm trying to use is an XML file. But i'm not sure how to include that URL into this code.

From your code:

```
$.get('sites.xml', function (d) {
       ^^^^^^^^^^
          Insert URI here.
```